# Continue to next for loop if current loop is 0

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, zero

It seems this is a general question of programming logic, as this issue seems to arise in my code regardless of what language it's coded in.

Basically I have 2 nested for loops, inside a for loop. The purpose of these for loops is to enumerate all possible values between two sets of values.

The problem with the code is that is the second set of values contains a 0 the values won't enumerate.

Say for example we want to enumerate all values between 0,0,0 and 1,1,1, this works perfectly fine, as each nested loop is processed. However is we try to calculate between 0,0,0 and 0,1,0 the loop will not continue on to the next loop, instead it will exit the loop and continue on to the rest of the code.

```
for ($i1=$coords1[0]; $i1<=$coords2[0]; $i1++) { //if $coords2[0] = 0 loop will fail
  for ($i2=$coords1[1]; $i2<=$coords2[1]; $i2++) { //if $coords2[1] = 0 loop will fail
    for ($i3=$coords1[2]; $i3<=$coords2[2]; $i3++) {//if $coords2[2] = 0 loop will fail
      $blocks.= $i1.",".$i2.",".$i3."|";
    }
  }
}
return $blocks;
```

Full code: [PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/in8-uaq)

Comment: Hmm...  you would THINK that in your example, the nested loop should be executed at least once, since you are using `<=` as your evaluator.  Looking at your code, it seems like it would work just fine...  /thinking cap on.

Comment: I recreated your code using Javascript, and it seems to work okay.   Take a look here:   http://jsfiddle.net/9A5dL/.    Using 000,111 generated 8 responses, as expected.   Using 000,010 generates 2 responses, also as expected,   Does this look right to you?   (make sure to have your JS console open when running the code)

Comment: Here's an full example of my script hosted on my server. You can see in [LINK1](http://projectbuilder.info/blockcalc.php?coord1=1,0,1&coord2=1,1,1) (comparing 1,0,1 and 1,1,1) that the calculation is preformed as expected, but in [LINK2](http://projectbuilder.info/blockcalc.php?coord1=1,0,1&coord2=1,1,0)  (comparing 1,0,1 and 1,1,0) that no results are returned.

Comment: Yes it seems to function perfectly in javascript, and also in a few other languages, but not in php. EDIT: EDIT: Nope it's still broke.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct.   When I click your LINK1, I'm seeing 12 results shown, with lots of 2's in the results.   This shouldn't be, as your range is from 0 to 1.    In my test, I'm seeing two results for that combo.   For LINK2, there are no results, which IS actually correct.   There are no valid combinations with those two sets of numbers.

Comment: This was a result of testing adding +1 to my final values to allow fallthrough, please ctrl+f5 the pages to see the current correct output. Also here is the full code [http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/in8-uaq](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/in8-uaq)

Comment: No the output for link 2 should be 

All Between: 1,1,0|1,1,1|1,0,0|1,0,1|
Number Of Blocks: 4
(I am using the same code in autoit to get these CORRECT results, in autoit, I was able to FORCE the interpreter to continue through the loops by telling them to count backwards if the final value is 0, though I've had no such luck with php)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45840/discussion-between-stormageddon-s-anderson-and-charlie74)

Comment: I disagree with your expected results for LINK2, which is either where the error is, or where we are not clear as to what you're looking for.   Using `1,0,1` and `1,1,0`, comparing the third value, there is no # 1 <= 0.  Based on this alone, the function returns no results.

Comment: As stated in the chat "The purpose of this function is to calculate all possible values between the two given values, so no matter what the two values are (unless they are the same) there will be greater than 0 results." Though the third value is 1 <= 0, thus causing the function to not return, it should still give the values of the first two nested if loops.

Comment: To continue that, as for LINK1 comparing `1,0,1` and `1,1,1`, only the middle value changes, and there are only two possibilities.   These are **1,0,1** and **1,1,1**.

Comment: I'm trying to calulate all possible locations on a 3D graph between two 3d sets of points, I don't know how better to explain this, but as I've said, unless the two POINTS on the GRAPH are IDENTICAL there is SOME DISTANCE between them, and as a result, there are GREATER than ZERO "chunks" between those TWO points. Edit: saw you get what I'm trying to do in chat now, sorry for any confusion!

Comment: Haha yeah, knowing that the values were *points on a graph* made all the difference.   Otherwise, it just didn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to copy this over from our chat, I believe this is the solution:

```
<?php
$set1 = explode(",", '1,0,1');
$set2 = explode(",", '1,1,0');

$allbetween = _allbetween($set1, $set2);
echo 'All Between: '.$allbetween.'<br/>';
$allcount = count(explode("|", $allbetween))-1;
echo 'Number Of Blocks: '.$allcount;

function _allbetween($coords1, $coords2) {
$blocks = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
        if ($coords1[$i] > $coords2[$i]) {
            $tmp = $coords1[$i];
            $coords1[$i] = $coords2[$i];
            $coords2[$i] = $tmp;
        }
    }

for ($i1=$coords1[0]; $i1<=$coords2[0]; $i1++)
  {
        for ($i2=$coords1[1]; $i2<=$coords2[1]; $i2++)
            {
                for ($i3=$coords1[2]; $i3<=$coords2[2]; $i3++)
                    {
                        $blocks.= $i1.",".$i2.",".$i3."|";
                    }
            }
  }
return $blocks;
}
?>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cxu-a46)

The reason this works is that there is a swap loop at the beginning of your function, which swaps any of the three sets of values if the first is greater than the second.   This ensures that all values "between" them can be calculated.

Edit:  Fixing the demo link to the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

the break; will do. see more information in the link:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 0):

Your loops will never loop as you are setting each initial value to the end range value. Instead use:

```
for ($i1=0; $i1<=$coords2[0]; $i1++)
...
etc
```

In terms of fall-through, try the following:

```
for ($i1=0; $i1<=$coords2[0] + 1; $i1++)
...
etc
```

Comment: That's not the case..... my script is counting from one value two another (calculating all the values inbetween) This setting the initial count to 0, and adding +1 to the final count value, result in an inaccurate count result. see [link](http://projectbuilder.info/blockcalc.php?coord1=1,0,1&coord2=1,1,1) and [link](http://projectbuilder.info/blockcalc.php?coord1=1,0,1&coord2=1,1,0) for examples

Comment: @joshd: the loops are initializing from coords **1**, and then testing against coords **2**. Even if they were initializing/testing on the same array, the loops should run at least ONCE because the comparison is `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the confusion! In that case, have you looked at using while instead of for loops?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: Dumping out your two $coords arrays:

$coords1:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

$coords2:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

On your first iteration:

```
   $coords1[0] => 1 
   $coords2[0] => 0

   1 <= 0 -> FALSE
```

so your outermost loop NEVER executes at all.

Comment: I know this is the problem, but I need to FORCE the loops to execute even if they initially return a value of false (and thus do nothing). Edit: and I need to do this without changing the numerical values, as this creates invalid calculations.

Comment: Why? You're trying to redefine "false" as "true", which means your loop could never terminate, because the condition would never go "real false", just your "fake false".

Comment: Perhaps sorting your arrays in descending order show up first would help, as long as you sort both the same way. That'd put the zero values at the end of the array and wouldn't terminate things until the non-zero values have been processed.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are searching for

[GOTO function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)

And for the

[Continue function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: Using GOTO to jump in and out of loops is a terrible idea.